# How can I move/zoom the camera in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic.
I'm trying to make an AR-Application. For that Issue I want to get a picture stream out of RVIZ.

I tried the camera-Display from RVIZ. to get an Image from an UR10-Robot, which I could modify. I only get an very small image of the scene.

How can I move and zoom the camera picture?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348096/how-can-i-move/zoom-the-camera-in-rviz?/) by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really want to use RViz plugins for this (as I'm not entirely sure it's supposed to be used like this), I'd recommend:

- to render arbitrary points of view: use [lucasw/rviz_camera_stream](https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_camera_stream): it's an RViz plugin, so you can just add it to your RViz configuration
- to control the camera (focus, zoom level, fov): look at [AIS-Bonn/rviz_cinematographer](https://github.com/AIS-Bonn/rviz_cinematographer). From the documentation: An rqt plugin to create and edit trajectories for the rviz camera and record its views in a video.

And a comment:

> I'm trying to make an AR-Application.

I'd take a look at how previous implementations, such as [ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins](https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins) (forks are more up-to-date), [AndreGilerson/rviz_vive](https://github.com/AndreGilerson/rviz_vive), [ROSIN FTP: rvis2ar](https://rosin-project.eu/ftp/rvis2ar), [IntelligentRoboticsLabs/ARViz](https://github.com/IntelligentRoboticsLabs/ARViz) and others have approached this.

Or perhaps even reuse some of them.

For an AR application it may be more efficient to directly alter the way RViz renders the scene.

It's based on OGRE, so anything is possible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2020-04-03**:
I allready found rviz_camera_stream and I thinks it's good.
I will look at your other suggestions. I hope they will be helpful.

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2020-04-17**:
I'm using rviz_camera_stream now. I can move and zoom when I move the tf-frame of the camera. And After I started the demo-file I can start the camera in other rviz-windows als well. Thanks for the answer.

P.S. It's important for me to get quick a solution, so OGRE would have been to much work.